# How to fix the emoji transparency - react-native-country-picker-modal - ReactNative

Tags: reactjs, typescript, react-native

```
  const [countryCode, setCountryCode] = useState<CountryCode>('FR');
  const [country, setCountry] = useState<Country>(null);
  const [withCountryNameButton, setWithCountryNameButton] = useState<boolean>(false);
  const [withFlag, setWithFlag] = useState<boolean>(true);
  const [withEmoji, setWithEmoji] = useState<boolean>(true);
  const [withFilter, setWithFilter] = useState<boolean>(true);

  const [withCallingCode, setWithCallingCode] = useState<boolean>(false);
  const onSelect = (country: Country) => {
    setCountryCode(country.cca2);
    setCountry(country);
  };

return (
    <TouchableOpacity activeOpacity={0.9} style={wrapperStyles} onPress={handleFocus}>
      <CountryPicker
        {...{
          countryCode,
          withFilter,
          withCountryNameButton,
          withCallingCode,
          onSelect,
        }}
      />
      <>
        {Icon && <Icon style={iconColor as StyleProp<ViewStyle>} />}
        <RNTextInput
          ref={textInput}
          style={inputStyles}
          placeholder={placeholder}
          onChangeText={onChangeText}
          defaultValue={defaultValue}
          onFocus={handleOnFocus}
          maxLength={maxLength}
          returnKeyType="done"
          onBlur={handleFocusOut}
          editable={!disabled}
          selectTextOnFocus={!disabled}
          {...rest}
        />
      </>
    </TouchableOpacity>
  );
```

This is the code I have.

And no matter which county code picker library I use, all the emojis looks transparent. I'm pretty sure it's not affected by the styling I use.

Here's what it looks like:

[image]

Any comment is much appreciated.

Comment: make  activeOpacity={1.0} and see

Comment: I did mate, no luck

Answer (score 2):

Treat emoji as text, I found that the default `<Text>` color in react native is not too black, it is slightly transparent. So I set `<Text>` style that contain the emoji to `color: 'black'`. And It works! Here is the example :
`<Text style={{color: 'black'}}></Text>`